# Invoking MS Graph API from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

We need to be able to programatically POST to the MS Graph API in order to bulk assign users to Access Packages, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/accesspackageassignmentrequest-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#examples

I am trying things like this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignmentRequests' -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body @{
               "requestType": "AdminAdd",
               "accessPackageAssignment":{
               "targetId":"xxx",
               "assignmentPolicyId":"xxx",
               "accessPackageId":"xxx"
                 }
}
```

Unfortunately though I get errors like this:

```
At line:2 char:29
+                "requestType": "AdminAdd",
+                             ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:2 char:29
+                "requestType": "AdminAdd",
+                             ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

Does anyone know how I should be doing it please?

Additionally, we have MFA enforced so the standard `$Cred = Get-Credential` will not work. What should I use instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors on the object syntax of your example:

- In Powershell properties are assigned with `=`
- Property names must not be quoted
- Property assignments are separated with semicolon

The correct command would look like:

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignmentRequests' -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body @{
               requestType = "AdminAdd";
               accessPackageAssignment = {
               targetId = "xxx";
               assignmentPolicyId = "xxx";
               accessPackageId = "xxx"
   }
}
```

Regarding MFA, you need to either use AppTokens or OAuth.

Comment: is there any safeguard parameter like -WhatIf ?

Comment: If you are referring to `Invoke-RestMethod`, there is no simulation parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to call Graph API endpoints through PowerShell as well. This was the script I ended up with:

```
Install-Module -Name MSAL.PS -RequiredVersion 4.2.1.3
Import-Module MSAL.PS
$clientId = "YOURCLIENTID"
$clientSecret = "YOURCLIENTSECRET"
$tenantId = "YOURTENANTID"

$ConfidentialClientOptions = New-Object Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions -Property @{ ClientId = $clientId; ClientSecret = $clientSecret; TenantId = $tenantId }
$ConfidentialClient = $ConfidentialClientOptions | New-MsalClientApplication
$tokenObj = Get-MsalToken -Scope 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' -ConfidentialClientApplication $ConfidentialClient
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2021-06-21T00:00:00Z&`$select=userPrincipalName,displayName,mail,signInActivity"
$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($tokenObj.AccessToken)"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get

$res.value | select userPrincipalName, displayName, mail, @{L="LastSignInDateTime";E={$_.signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime}} | Sort-Object -Property LastSignInDateTime
```

I wrote a blog post about it as well: https://engineerer.ch/2021/07/01/how-to-use-powershell-to-call-graph-api-endpoints/